# Embedding streetview picture in infowindow - Googlemaps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I'm using googlemaps v3/ASP.net MVC/Knockout for a location selection screen. I cannot get the streetview picture in the infowindow. I've tried several different examples. I can see that the image is being pulled down (viewable in the browser resources), but it will not display.

Does anyone see something I'm missing? It really seems like it should be working.  I do get a warning regarding "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream", but like I said I can see the image making it to the browser.

```
  // Function for creating a marker and adding to myMarkers array
  function addMarker(location, id) {
    var selector = "#hiddenBranch" + id;
    var html = $(selector)[0].innerHTML;

    var panSelector = "PanId" + id;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      distance: google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(location, centerCoords),
    });

    marker.setValues({id: id})

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
      if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: ''
      });
      infowindow.setContent(html);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);

      var panoramaOptions = {
        position: location,
        pov: {
          heading: 34,
          pitch: 10,
          zoom: 1
        }
      };

      var pano = null;
      google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'domready', function() {
        pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById(panSelector), panoramaOptions);
        pano.bindTo("position", marker);
        pano.setVisible(true);
      });

    });

    myMarkers.push(marker);
  }
```

Portion of the html. Repeated with Knockout.

```
        @*The content of this div will be displayed in infowindow*@ 
    <div style="display:none">
      <div data-bind="attr: {'id': HiddenDivId}"> 
        <div style="width:100px; height:100px" data-bind="attr: {'id': HiddenPanDivId}">

        </div>
        <input data-bind="value: Id" class="hiddenBranchId" type="hidden" value="">
        <input data-bind="value: DirectionLink" class="hiddenDirectionLink" type="hidden" value="">
        <ul>
          <li><h2></h2></li>
          <li data-bind="text: BranchName"></li>
          <li data-bind="text: StreetAddress"></li>
          <li><span data-bind="text: City"></span>, <span data-bind="text: Zip"></span>  <span data-bind="text: State"></span></li>
          <li><a href='#' class="branchSelectLink" onclick=selectBranch(this)>Select</a> | <a href="#" onclick=openDirectionWindow(this)>Directions here</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the size of the div into which you are placing the streetview?  Not sure if it will help, but, [working example with Streetview in infowindows](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_StreetViewInInfoWindowB.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues.

1. you open the infoWindow before you add the domready-event
2. **(more problematic)** you set the content of the infoWindow to the innerHTML of an  element that already exists inside the DOM, the result will be that the ID's of the elements are not unique anymore. I guess the panorama will be applied to the hidden element that already exists inside the DOM and not to the "clone" that has been applied to the content of the infoWindow.

possible solution for 2.

1. Don't use IDs, classNames or other attributes are sufficient to select elements and don't need to be unique
2. create a real clone instead of using innerHTML

   ```
        var html = $(selector).clone(true);
   ```
3. use the context-argument to access the node inside the clone (and not inside the original element)

   ```
        pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama($(panSelector,html)[0], 
                                                     panoramaOptions);
   ```

Comment: You're awesome. Thanks for taking the time to set me straight. I didn't even think about the fact that I was duplicating IDs. I changed the selector to a class..and it works great. Thanks again.